# Need for JSON during serialization

Tags: c, json

Ok we know if someone says he/she wants to send an integer over a network say using C,
we typically say:

- take care of endianness and
- watch out of size differences on different PC

If someone wants to send float, we might give additional advices...

Considering above possible problems, someone might say use: JSON.
My question is  how does JSON deal/defeat the above mentioned issues?
by just converting these data types to strings?

Answer (score 0):

When JSON is used, all data is converted to strings. It is up to library (or libraries) handling the serializarion/deserialization to produce/interpret the values

Answer (score 0):

Need to convert the `JSON` data to a string.

Answer (score 0):

JSON only has these types:

```
string
number
object
array
true
false
null
```

An integer would be a `number`.

```
{"int": 1}
```

The problems you mention are out of scope for JSON. They must be dealed by the programming languages and libraries creating and reading JSON.

**Edit:**

As described on http://json.org/, a `number` can be written using this form:

```
number
    int
    int frac
    int exp
    int frac exp 
int
    digit
    digit1-9 digits
    - digit
    - digit1-9 digits 
frac
    . digits
exp
    e digits
digits
    digit
    digit digits
e
    e
    e+
    e-
    E
    E+
    E-
```

This form is an abstraction level above endianess because that's a problem of bits and bytes. This form *does* allow the usual number types like integers and floats.

Comment: I asked this question like I said because people suggest using JSON to defeat the problems I mentioned in my question. Do you say JSON does not defeat those problems?

Comment: It does, by converting everything to string. Now when you read the data back, it is your responsibility to convert string back to desired type. Since converting takes place on target machine, you don't have to worry about endianness

Comment: @W.B.: that was my question exactly, so by converting data types to strings it defeats problems like endianness? and differences in data types? (just the answers don't mention it)

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of JSON compared to a hand-written protocol:

JSON is a standard.
JSON documents are human-readable. 
JSON documents document their contents. 
JSON document formats can be upgraded. 
JSON documents are structured. 
JSON documents are flexible. 
JSON documents can be checked through a JSON Schema.

You'd need some pretty good reason to use a proprietary binary format.

Comment: Would speed be considered a good reason? If you exchange tons of data, string convertion can kill your app. As an example look at speed difference of boost serialize text and binary archives

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated JSON is text-only protocol, so endianness or data type sizes don't directly affect.

However, text can encoded in many different encodings, and some of those encodings might have endianness issues (like UTF-16). Though for anything new you should use UTF-8 because it is widely used and has no those specific endianness issues.

Still, encoding is something you have to know about. There is no simple right choice between binary/text, only different set of problems and trade-offs.